# Making table rows generated via JQuery act as onClick page redirects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So I am pretty new to JQuery/HTML development of all kinds. Basically I am working on a project where I make an AJAX call that gets a bunch of usernames, dates, etc. regarding Craiglist-like sales that I put into a table format dynamically using JQuery and DOM.

I want to be able to make these elements in the table act as links so that if I click on a certain username, it will take me to their profile. I've tried different suggestions out there but none of them are for tables that are generated with JQuery and I think this is causing problems (but I don't think there is any way around that either). Some snippets of my code are as follows:

```
function displayCurrentSales(description, seller, date) {
     var sale = document.createElement("p");
     var table = document.getElementById("currentSalesTable");
     var row = table.insertRow(-1);
     var descriptionRow = row.insertCell(0);
     var userRow = row.insertCell(1);
     var dateRow = row.insertCell(2);
     descriptionRow.innerHTML = description;
     userRow.innerHTML = seller;
     userRow.onClick = "window.location.href = '../profilePage/index.html?username=' + seller;";
     dateRow.innerHTML = date;
 }
```

This is my code that I started with except for the userRow.onClick part which I added to try and make it work.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Another note, I also tried using JQuery with:    $('tr').click(blah blah blah) but it didn't work (I am guessing it had to do with the elements being created in JQuery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function displayCurrentSales(description, seller, date) {
     var sale = document.createElement("p");
     var table = document.getElementById("currentSalesTable");
     var row = table.insertRow(-1);
     var descriptionRow = row.insertCell(0);
     var userRow = row.insertCell(1);
     var dateRow = row.insertCell(2);
     descriptionRow.innerHTML = description;
     userRow.innerHTML = seller;
     dateRow.innerHTML = date;
     userRow.addEventListener('click', function(){
        window.location.href = '../profilePage/index.html?username=' + seller;
    }); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your heart set on using jQuery, you can get the desired results by using the live event handler "on". It will work on dynamically created elements. I would put the handler on the table itself, but filter it to your rows. Here's an example.

```
$('#currentSalesTable').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    window.location.href = '../profilePage/index.html?username=' + seller;
});
```

Note, the above assumes you have some way of getting the seller at the time of the click. You could store the seller value as a data attribute on each row to make this easier. In the end, your rows would look like this:

```
...
<tr data-seller="jdoe">
...
```

Then, the event handler would grab that value like so:

```
$('#currentSalesTable').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var seller = $(this).data('seller');
    window.location.href = '../profilePage/index.html?username=' + seller;
});
```